# Avoid duplicates while syncing MongoDB and Elasticsearch with Logstash JDBC plugin

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, jdbc, logstash, mongo-jdbc-driver

I'm trying to keep a MongoDB collection in sync with an Elasticsearch index using Logstash.

I'm using the Logstash JDBC plugin with the [DBSchema](https://dbschema.com/jdbc-driver/MongoDb.html) JDBC Driver Library for this.

This is the configuration file I'm using for logstash:-

```
input {
  jdbc{
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.dbschema.MongoJdbcDriver"
    jdbc_driver_library => "/path/to/mongojdbc1.8.jar"
    jdbc_user => ""
    jdbc_password => ""
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/db1"
    statement => "db.collection1.find({ }, { '_id': false })"
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://127.0.0.1:9200"]
    index => "testing"
    user => ""
    password => ""
  }
}
```

This works alright, but when I run logstash multiple times, the records are inserted multiple times into Elasticsearch. I do not want records to be re-written. Also, if I modify a document and run logstash again, it should change the same record in Elasticsearch without creating a new document. How do I go about achieving this?

Comment: It will only update the same document in elasticsearch if you use the option `document_id` in your logstash output with some unique identifier from your source, if you do not use it, elasticsearch will generate an unique id for every document,  do you have a unique identifier field in your source?

Comment: try adding `record_last_run => true` and  `last_run_metadata_path => "/usr/share/logstash/bin/since"` to your jdbc section in logstash. you can read more about it here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html

Comment: @leandrojmp got it, I need to set a unique identifier for each document first

Comment: @eladyanai that's another good solution, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sync up your documents by ids. 
Here is the link to [Logstash Elasticsearch output plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-outputs-elasticsearch-doc_as_upsert), on part with options you need.

So regarding docs you must set `doc_as_upsert` to true, and pass document_id in output.

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["http://127.0.0.1:9200"]
    index => "testing"
    user => ""
    password => "",
    doc_as_upsert => true,
    document_id => "%{id}"
  }
}
```

Note the `document_id => "%{id}"` - id here is you doc id field name.